# How to simplify my JavaScript function with a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following JavaScript function to retrieve stock information from Yahoo Finance. I would like to streamline the code with a for loop, to avoid repeating these three lines:

```
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.Symbol);
cell.appendChild(newText);
```

I tried to replace the above with these lines, to no avail. Would you have any suggestion?

```
var dataElement=[data.query.results.quote.Symbol,
    data.query.results.quote.StockExchange,
    data.query.results.quote.Ask,
    data.query.results.quote.Bid,
    data.query.results.quote.PERatio,
    data.query.results.quote.DividendYield,
    data.query.results.quote.PriceBook];

for (i = 0; i < dataElement.length; i++) {  
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    var newText =document.createTextNode(dataElement[i]);
    cell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

Here is the complete HTML / js code, without the for loop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-GB" xml:lang="en-GB">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>
        Retrieve stock data from Yahoo Finance
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputSymbol" />

    <table id='stockDataTable'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Symbol</td>
                <td>Stock Exchange</td>
                <td>Ask</td>
                <td>Bid</td>
                <td>PE Ratio</td>
                <td>Dividend Yield</td>
                <td>Price-to-Book Ratio</td>
            </tr>           
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" id='status'></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" onClick="addTicker();">Add Ticker to Table</button>
    <button type="submit" onClick="deleteTicker();">Remove Ticker from Table</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTicker() {
            var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
            var symbol = $("#inputSymbol").val();
            var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");

            var table = document.getElementById("stockDataTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

            $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
                .done(function (data) {

                    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.Symbol);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);

                    var cell = row.insertCell(1);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.StockExchange);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);

                    var cell = row.insertCell(2);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.Ask);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);

                    var cell = row.insertCell(3);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.Bid);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);

                    var cell = row.insertCell(4);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.PERatio);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);

                    var cell = row.insertCell(5);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.DividendYield);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);

                    var cell = row.insertCell(6);
                    var newText = document.createTextNode(data.query.results.quote.PriceBook);
                    cell.appendChild(newText);
            })
                .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                    $("#status").text('Request failed: ' + err);
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function deleteTicker() {
            var symbol = $("#inputSymbol").val();
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById("stockDataTable");
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
                if(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == symbol) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see an array like `['Symbol','StockExchange',...]` coming into play here where `quote.Symbol` and `quote[array[0]]` are equivalent.

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get errors?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I get the following error message: TypeError: data.query is undefined
 

var dataElement = [ data.query.results.quote.Symbol,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/KBJT4/10/**

There are a few ways to skin this cat but this way is looping the keys of your `quote` structure.  Here is some of the code but run the fiddle to see it in action.

```
/*simulating your data object*/
var data = {
      query: {
        results: {
          quote: {
            Symbol: 'Symbol_Value',
            StockExchange: 'StockExchange_Value',
            Ask: 'Ask_Value',
            Bid: 'Bid_Value',
            PERatio: 'PERatio_Value',
            DividendYield: 'DividendYield_Value',
            PriceBook: 'PriceBook_Value'
          }
        }
      }
    };

var i = 0;
var tempData = data.query.results.quote; /*shorten this up*/

//loop object by keys
for (var key in tempData) {
    i = i+1;

    //the alerts show you it's working
    //just replace the alerts with the commented out code

    //var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    alert('row.insertCell('+i+')');

    alert(key+': '+tempData[key]);

    //var newText = document.createTextNode('+tempData[key]+');
    var newText = tempData[key]; //you will remove this line also, its here just so the final alert will work
    alert('var newText = document.createTextNode('+tempData[key]+');');

    //cell.appendChild(newText);
    alert('cell.appendChild('+newText+');');
}
```

**UPDATE:** I added this line to fiddle: `alert(key+': '+data[key]);`.  It'll help you understand it a little better.  Plus if you want to show the key and it's value instead of just the value, this is how you'd do it.

**UPDATE:** @user3006803 And here is a real working example that doesn't use your hardcoded data structure. It really shows **EVERYTHING** for the `APL` symbol.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Dp8px/14/**

*(after you click the button notice the scroll bar that appears, there's a lot of data in the result block)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Here is my script after modification: http://jsfiddle.net/lcazarre/Gc5bd/. I did not manage to make it work though. I get this error message: "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=[object%20Object]&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env".

Comment: I'll check it out in a little bit, ~30min

Comment: @user3006803 You had a number of things wrong with your fiddle. A lot of your code simply cannot run in that fiddle cause of missing code, it's not a complete functioning webpage. (1) I hard-coded the stock symbol to `APL` (even though it's not being used, your `data` is hard-coded) (2) You don't need `<script>` tags when you are in the JavaScript block (3) You didn't include the jQuery library.  Try this one: **http://jsfiddle.net/Dp8px/12/** You were also referencing a `status` area that didn't exist so I added a `status` div and that's where the results appear. This should get you on track.

Comment: @user3006803 And here is a real working example that doesn't use your hardcoded `data` structure.  It really shows EVERYTHING for the `APL` symbol. **http://jsfiddle.net/Dp8px/14/** (after you click the button notice the scroll bar that appears, there's a lot of data in the result block) If you need futher help, like formatting for putting it in a table or something then that would be a new question.  I believe I have answered your original question.  Thanks!

Comment: I thank you very much for your kind help. I will study your code right now. I apologise for not having modified the code and activated jsQuery when I pasted it in jsFiddle. I had copied it from my own HTML page without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of the webpage, thanks to gfrobenius' help. I have also extended the JavaScript code to enable retrieving a list of tickers (separated by commas).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-GB" xml:lang="en-GB">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>
        Retrieve stock data from Yahoo Finance
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Yahoo_finance.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputSymbols" />

    <table id='stockDataTable'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>           
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" id='status'></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" onClick="addTickers();">Add List of Tickers to Table</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTickers() {
            var stringSymbols = $("#inputSymbols").val();
            var arraySymbols = stringSymbols.split(",");
            for (var i=0; i<arraySymbols.length; i++) {
                addTicker(arraySymbols[i]);
            }
        }
        function addTicker(symbol) {
            var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
            var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");
            var table = document.getElementById("stockDataTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

            $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
                .done(function (data) {
                    //add table header to show symbols, if it does not exist
                    if (table.rows.length == 0) {
                        var tableHasHeader = false;
                        var rowHeader = table.insertRow(0);
                    } else {
                        var tableHasHeader = true;
                    }
                    var rowData = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

                    //loop object by keys
                    var i = 0;
                    var tempData = data.query.results.quote;
                    for (var key in tempData) {

                        //add symbol to the header, if it was not populated yet
                        if (tableHasHeader == false) {
                            var cellHeader = rowHeader.insertCell(i);
                            var newText = document.createTextNode(key);
                            cellHeader.appendChild(newText);                
                        }

                        //add data
                        var cellData = rowData.insertCell(i);
                        var newText = document.createTextNode(tempData[key]);
                        cellData.appendChild(newText);

                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                    for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
                        if (typeof table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === "undefined") {
                            alert("undefined");
                            table.deleteRow(i);
                        }                       
                    }
            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                $("#status").text('Request failed: ' + err);
            });
            //alert(table.rows.length);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```